# Ngrx RxJS cancelable interval poling

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5, ngrx

I would like to implement some kind of a polling mechanism using NgRX and RxJS. At some time during an application runtime user clicks a button, applications starts to poll data every 30 seconds. Each response from BE has a status. Once status has changed - polling should be stopped. I'm thinking about a better solution. Initial idea was to do something like described in this article: https://blog.sstorie.com/building-an-angular-2-reactive-auto-logout-timer-with-the-redux-pattern/

But this solution is not so cancelable. Maybe you know a better way?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't unsubscribe? `let subscription = observable.subscribe()` then later `subscription.unsubscribe()`